# How many gold badges are there?

Tags: support, badges

I see about 19 gold badges in the [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=General&filter=gold), but I have seen some users that have 40+ gold badges. Are the user badges shown a sum of all badges obtained from all Stack Exchange sites, or are these extra badges obtained some other way?

Comment: Some badges can be earned multiple times.

Comment: You can get gold tag badges as well.

Comment: The reason some people have so many gold badges is because they have earned it multiple times. Same goes for silver and bronze badges.

Comment: You can see how people earned their badges by going to the "Activity" tab on the user's profile, and clicking the "badges" tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are the user badges shown a sum of all badges obtained from all stack exchange sites,

No, badges are site specific.

> or are these extra badges obtained some other way?

There are several ways:

Besides those documented gold badges you may achieve gold badges for particular tags you've been participating notably.

If you've got the gold badge for a particular tag, you have the privilege to directly close vote questions tagged with that as duplicate.

Also some badges may be earned multiple times.

---

The same applies for silver and bronze badges of course.